# Google Search API Keywords

Tags: api, search, keyword

When I put any keyword in search area it will display, but in my php, I always display. I want change the Query in API for any keywords I want and search.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Google Search API</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="content">
    <input type="text" id="Query">
    <button id="add">Search</button>
  </div>

  <script>
    function hndlr(response) {
      for (var i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++) {
        var item = response.items[i];

        // in production code, item.htmlTitle should have the HTML entities escaped.
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += "<br>" + "<b>" + item.title + "</b>" + "<br>" + item.snippet + "<br>" + "<a href='" + item.link + "'>" + item.displayLink + "</a>";

      }
    }
  </script>

  <script id="searchme"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var search_query = 'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=Query&cx=004123968310343535430%3Aaxml6iel9yo&key=AIzaSyDxPcphnrcN9_dfkRkFTbwkv44m1-HI1Hg&callback=hndlr';
    document.getElementById('searchme').src = search_query;
  </script>


</body>

</html>
```